# Find the mean for every selected rows in R from csv file

Tags: r

I have more than 10,000 data as row and 14 columns in my csv. I wanted to find the mean and SD for every 128 in the data for all 14 columns. Is that possible to get the statistic for every n where i state 128, means (0-128, 129-256, 257-384, ......till end). Any script or code available?

Comment: Is it PHP, R or Matlab?

Comment: Try `lapply(df1, function(x) tapply(x, (seq_along(x)-1)%/%128, FUN = mean))`

Comment: @Jorgen. It`s R

Answer (score -2, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the columns of dataset, then created a grouping variable with `%/%` and get the `mean` using `tapply`

```
lapply(df1, function(x) tapply(x, (seq_along(x)-1)%/%128, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(c(NA, 1:10), 140, replace=TRUE),
      col2 = sample(c(NA, 1:3), 140, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I only can get the mean for the first column. The rest columns states NA.

Comment: @shan11 If you have NA elements, then use `na.rm = TRUE`.  Updated the post

Comment: It still getting the same value if use na.rm = TRUE. But if wanted to find sd then can get value for all columns.

Comment: @shan11 That is strange.  It works for the reproducible example I created.  But, since you haven't provided anything, I am not sure what is happening at your end

Comment: lapply(Subject.1, function(x) tapply(x, (seq_along(x)-1)%/%128, FUN = mean, na.rm=TRUE))
$V1
        0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7 
 492.1875 1488.2812 2488.2812 3488.2812 4488.2812 5488.2812 6488.2812 7488.2812 
        8 
7992.1875 

$V2
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 

$V3
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

Comment: @shan11 I have updated with a reproducible example.  So, if you check that, it is giving me output without any NAs

Comment: It works for me now. Is there any chance to save all the output as new csv file in different directory because i`m planning to do the cycling for 128,64 and 32.

Comment: @shan11 Yes, you can save it as a new csv file.  `res <- do.call(cbind, lapply(df1, function(x) tapply(x, (seq_along(x)-1)%/%128, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE))); write.csv(res, file = paste0(yourpathtonewdirectory, "/file1.csv", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)`